# Calling Instagram APi from 2 different country's IP address?

Tags: api, ip, instagram

What is the difference when we call Instagram API from 2 different country's IP address ex say US and England? Is there a difference in the data returned?

Comment: Which endpoint? Have you noticed anything different, or hypothesizing?

Comment: I am talking in general. I'll be using multiple proxies to call Instagram API. I just want to make sure that if I call the api with 2 different country's proxies I should not get different results. For ex if I call this end point - > https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent  from US proxy and the same call with England proxy. Will I get the same result of different result?